# Get size of header of an image

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

I want to know how to get the size of an image header. I have been searchin in internet but I have not found information about how to get an image (bitmap) header in java/android.

Anyone has an idea or example?

What I have been trying to do is next but it's not working properly because the image cannot be opened:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b        = baos.toByteArray();  
        byte[] b_header = new byte[8];
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, b_header, 0, 8);
        bos.write(b_header);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
```

Comment: *"I want to know how to get the size of an image header."*  Why?

Comment: Which header of a bitmap, there are several http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format If you are talking about the first Header, it's 14 bytes.

Comment: @zero298 I am talking about all the header information of (png) file. I want to ignore all pixel information and only get the information block of the image.

Comment: @MarcForn I'm still not understanding.  You do mean the header of the file structure right? Because again, that's fixed.  The header of a PNG is 8 bytes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics What do you mean you want to ignore the pixel information and only get the information block?  Also, edit your question so that you state you are working with PNGs

Comment: @zero298 what I want to do is to encrypt the pixels information not the entire .png file. Because after the ecnrypton I want to open the image with an image viewer. To do that I need to not encrypt the header because the system could know that the files is an image.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest writing code to handle PNG manipulation yourself unless that is the main goal of the project.  Instead, I'd find a library that would handle the loading of a PNG for you and then scramble the chunks that it can get for you.  I found a nice PNG java library here:

[PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/)

Also, I wrote a small code snip based on their examples to get you on the right track to scrambling your images.

```
public static void encryptPng(File in, File out) {

   PngReader pngReader = new PngReader(in);
   PngWriter pngWriter = new PngWriter(out, pngReader.imgInfo, false);

   pngWriter.copyChunksFrom(pngReader.getChunksList());

   for (int row = 0; row < pngReader.imgInfo.rows; row++) {
      ImageLineInt lineInt = (ImageLineInt) pngReader.readRow();
      adjustLine(lineInt, pngReader.imgInfo);
      pngWriter.writeRow(lineInt);
   }

   pngReader.close();
   pngWriter.close();

}

public static void adjustLine(ImageLineInt line, ImageInfo info) {
   /*
    Scramble the line with some reversable algorithm so that it can't be read
    */
}
```